# Titanium - How to close View that is defined in another .js file

Tags: titanium, view

I have one window defined in a `FirstView.js` and a View defined in `Settings.js`.

I add the Settings View to the `FirstView` Window doing this:

```
var Settings = require('ui/common/Settings');
var Settings = new Settings();
self.add(Settings);
```

And now, when users press "back" button i need to remove the Settings View from main window.
I know that i could do this with `self.remove(Settings)` if both codes were in the same .js file.

But, in this case, how can i remove the Settings View from the main `FirstView` Window?

Comment: `self.remove(Settings)` will still work. Can you show the Settings code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use Application level events.

in Settings.js and when you click on back button

```
Ti.App.fireEvent("backSetting");
```

and in FirstView.js

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("backSetting",function(e){
                       self.remove(Setting);
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use a container for settings?

e.g:

```
var FirstView=Ti.UI.createWindow();

var contentSetting=Ti.UI.createView({
  height:Ti.UI.SIZE //or Ti.UI.FILL,
  width:Ti.UI.SIZE //or Ti.UI.FILL
});

FirstView.add(contentSetting);

var Settings = require('ui/common/Settings');
var Settings = new Settings();

contentSetting.add(Settings);

FirstView.addEventListener('android:back', function(e){
 //remove view
 $.contentSetting.removeAllChildren();
});
```